# PyCharm - Auto-reloading Django dev server after template changes

Tags: django, docker-compose, django-templates, pycharm, gunicorn

How to make my PyCharm to reload Django dev server after i make changes in templates?

It reloads on save on every other changes but not for template changes.

server is starting by `docker compose up`

We are using Django 3.2.16

**entrypoint.sh**:

```
exec gunicorn app.wsgi:application --config gunicorn.py --reload
```

**settings.py**

```
[...]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "app.context_processors.get_version",
                "app.context_processors.get_env",
            ]
        },
    }
]
[...]
```

Comment: The default `runserver` command does not need to reload for templates normally. Your problem is, that with just changing and saving the file, those changes do probably not take place in the container. Try: 1. start docker container and start server 2. opt into container and change one html file 3. check how it gets displayed without restarting server or container. The changes should be visible.

Comment: no changes visible without ```cftr+c``` -> and running ```docker compose up``` again.
chnages on all other files like ```views.py``` or ```settings.py``` etc make webserver to reload just fine on ```ctrl-s```